# How to show if a function is idempotent?

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics, proof-writing, idempotents

> Let $f:B\to B$ be a function, with $B'\subseteq B$ the range of $f$. Show that $f$ is idempotent if $b' \in B$ is a fixed point of $f$? Show that $f$ is an idempotent function!

I am having trouble writing a clear proof for this question. I looked up definitions online and found out that a function is idempotent iff $f \circ f = f$. In this question, we have the identity function:
$$(1_{B'} \circ 1_{B})(b') \implies 1_{B'} (1_{B}(b'))\implies 1_{B'}(b')$$
I am stuck after this point. I am not sure about the correct answer to this question. Please help me out! Please suggest how to write a correct proof for this question. What am I missing in my explanation? Thanks!

Comment: Why should we do it for you?

Comment: What are your thoughts on the question?  What have you tried so far?

Comment: I am sorry I am new here! I am editing the question for more details!

Comment: I have added all the details of what I have done so far! Please help me out

Comment: You're missing a lot in your answer.  It seems that in your attempt at a proof, you tried to showed that the identity function is idempotent, which is not what we want.

Comment: I've changed my answer to include a detailed proof.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you've translated or copied the question incorrectly. Precise phrasing is important.

> Let $f:B \to B$, and let $B' \subseteq B$ denote the range of $f$.  Show that $f$ is idempotent if **every** $b' \in B'$ is a fixed point of $f$.

**Hint:** It's important to understand the definitions at work here

- We say that a function $f:B \to B$ is *idempotent* if $f \circ f = f$.  That is, for every $b \in B$, we have $f(f(b)) = f(b)$.
- We say that $x$ is a *fixed point* of $f$ if $f(x) = x$.
- We say that an element $b'$ is in the *range of $f$* if there exists a $b$ for which $b' = f(b)$.

If you really understand the definitions, it should be easy to see how they can interact.  In particular: if $f(b)$ is a fixed point of $f$, what can we say about $f(f(b))$?

---

Here's a correct proof:

> Suppose that every point of the image of $f$ is a fixed point of $f$. That is, for every $b$ in $B$, the element $f(b)$ is a fixed point of $f$.  So, for every $b$ in $B$, we have $f(f(b)) = f(b)$, which is to say that for every $b \in B$ $[f \circ f](b) = f(b)$.  Thus, we conclude that $f \circ f = f$.  That is, $f$ must be idempotent.

Comment: If I follow all the suggestions in your answer, I end up having statements written in my questions. However, is it all I need to write a correct proof for this question? I request you to please read my question details and get back to me. Thanks much for helping me out!